# ByteBuddy - Getting error while passing array in annotation's value

Tags: bytecode, byte-buddy

Consider an example of building a new class instance and adding below annotation.

.annotateMethod(
  AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(OneToMany.class)
    .define("cascade", **new CascadeType[]{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}**)
    .define("fetch", FetchType.LAZY)
    .define("targetEntity", EntityB.class)
    .build())

Everything works fine except assigning the "cascade" value. Getting compile-time error because **.define** method is not expecting an array of enums.

How can I pass an array as an Annotaion's value assignment?

For example, I want to assign an array of enum as below:

@ManyToMany(cascade = **{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}**)

Comment: One minute of search: [`defineEnumerationArray`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.4/net/bytebuddy/description/annotation/AnnotationDescription.Builder.html#defineEnumerationArray-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-T...-). I suppose, pressing the completion key in your IDE right at the location of the error would have given you the answer in even two seconds…

Comment: Yes, Thank you.
.defineEnumerationArray("cascade",CascadeType.class, CascadeType.ALL)

Answer (score 1):

As Holger points out, use [`defineEnumerationArray` as documented in the javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/latest/net/bytebuddy/description/annotation/AnnotationDescription.Builder.html).

The overloads are limited to avoid a conflict with defining a single enum value property compared to defining an enumeration array with a single value.